# Insert msg.payload into LIFX Node as a value

Tags: node-red, lifx

I want to control the brightness of my LIFX bulb by injecting the value of a slider on my NodeRed Dashboard into the `node-red-contrib-lifx-api` node.
I managed to control the light if I am using fixed values but somehow it won't take the msg.payload parameter. Also, no error message is shown on the debug stream.

my flow looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Is `{{msg.payload}}` the right syntax to use in this field? the double brackets `{{` are working on my other nodes so I am using them here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes need to be explicitly built to support pulling values in from the input message. Most of them do not use mustache (`{{}}`) syntax, the preferred way to do it if supported is to leave that value empty in the config dialogue (if you set a value it should not be overriden by an incoming message) and where the values come from in `msg` should be documented in the info side bar.

Looking at the [src](https://github.com/alisdairjsmyth/node-red-contrib-lifx-api/blob/master/lifx-api/lifx.js#L202) for the node it looks like it will take the brightness from `msg.brightness` so you probably want to use a change node to move the value from `msg.payload` to `msg.brightness` before the set-state node.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out a similar trick which works.

I parse the json string from the documentation to the msg.payload Object and change the brightness:

`var lampSettings = JSON.parse('{    "selector": "id:***",    "power": "on",    "brightness": 0.5}');
lampSettings.brightness = msg.payload;
msg.payload = lampSettings;`

return msg;